# How to get rid of the blank area at the bottom of tableview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6, qtableview

[image]

There's always an bland area at the bottom of the tableview of QTableWidget.

How can I get rid of this blank area, and let the tableview only display the row and column according to the given data?

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to get.

Comment: Do you want the table to expand the items vertically or do you want to change the color of the part you point to?

Comment: I want the table to expand vertcally and the height of rows balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `Stretch` as resizeMode to the verticalheader():

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    w.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(4, 4))
    w.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    w.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]